# Mapping one number range to another

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I'm trying to map one decimal number range to another.  In the example below it's the range 0.0 -> 2.0 mapped to 0.0 -> 0.8.  I can't seem to get the output range to ever finish at 0.8 - it stops short at 0.722.  The issue I think is how the scale variable is calculated but I'm unsure as to how to fix it.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```js
function myscale (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max, factor)
{
 // number map
 var scale = Math.max(0.0, num - in_min) / (in_max - in_min);

 // calculate easing curve
 var r = out_min + (Math.pow(scale, factor) * (out_max - out_min));

 // 64-bit floating point representation fix
 r = parseFloat(r.toFixed(10));

 // return mapped scale number
 return r;
}

var text = "";
var i;

for (i = 0.0; i <= 2.0; i = i + 0.1)
{ 
    text += myscale(i, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.8, 2) + "<br />";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b>Numbers mapped from 0 to 0.8</b>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach and iterate until then value is smaller than the wanted values. Finally take the greates value and call the function with this value outside of the `for` loop with a value withour floating points errors of adding numbers.

```js
function myscale (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max, factor) {
 // number map
 var scale = Math.max(0.0, num - in_min) / (in_max - in_min);

 // calculate easing curve
 var r = out_min + (Math.pow(scale, factor) * (out_max - out_min));

 // 64-bit floating point representation fix
 r = parseFloat(r.toFixed(10));

 // return mapped scale number
 return r;
}

var text = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.1) { 
    text += myscale(i, 0, 2, 0, 0.8, 2) + "<br />";
}
text += myscale(2, 0, 2, 0, 0.8, 2) + "<br />";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<b>Numbers mapped from 0 to 0.8</b>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: In general, we cannot expect the final `i` in `for (i = start; i <= end; i += increment)` to be within one epsilon (relative to `end`, that is, scaled by `end` or the least power of two not greater than it) even if `end`−`start` is a multiple of `increment`, because there are multiple rounding errors, one in each addition of `increment`, and there is no reason to expect they add up to only one epsilon. So this is not a proper solution. A proper solution is to iterate with integers or other values that have exact representations, then scale the iteration variable to the desired interval.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you are right. ich changes the for loop and use the final value as single call.

Comment: @NinaScholz appreciate the answer and it does solve it but (much along the lines of Eric's comments) it does feel like a make shift fix after something has gone wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil any possibility of an example of how to implement your solution?

Comment: @garrettlynch: I have supplied an answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz: The new code is also not a general solution as the repeated addition of an increment can produce a value that is very near but less than the end value, such as 1.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375. Then there would be two executions of the routine with a value near the end value, one in the loop and the extra one after it. I already stated a proper solution: Use integers.

Comment: @garrettlynch: No, when I wrote “I have supplied an answer,” I had literally typed an answer, with code, into StackOverflow’s answer form and submitted it. Refresh the page.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, at least, you need to get a floating point number, even by taking an integer counter. if the final value doesnot reach the wanted result, `myscale` could be changed to accept a large number (Infinity) for getting the max proposed wanted value.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I have provided a complete solution. It **does** transform the integer counter into the desired floating-point value. There is no need to change `myscale`, and that would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Non-integer values should not be used for loop control unless you have properly crafted the loop for floating-point arithmetic. Generally, it is easier to implement loop control with integer arithmetic. (When non-integer values are used in loop control, floating-point rounding errors may cause the iterator value to be slightly above or below the end value in the iteration when ideally it would equal the end value. This makes controlling exactly which iteration the loop ends on difficult.)

For the case in the question, where we want to iterate by one-tenth, a simple solution is to scale by 10, so 0, 2.0, and 0.1 become 0, 20, and 1:

```
for (var ProxyI = 0; ProxyI <= 20; ProxyI = ProxyI += 1)
{
    var RealI = ProxyI / 10.0;
    text += myscale(RealI, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.8, 2) + "<br />";
}
```

In general, if we want to iterate from `Start` to `End`, inclusive, by `Increment`, where `Increment` ideally evenly divides the distance from `Start` to `End` but floating-point arithmetic interferes, then we can use:

```
var NumberOfIntervals = Math.round((End - Start) / Interval);
for (var ProxyI = 0; ProxyI <= NumberOfIntervals; ProxyI = ProxyI + 1)
{
    var RealI = Start + I / NumberOfIntervals * (End - Start);
    …
}
```

The design here is that `NumberOfIntervals` is set to be the integer number of intervals we expect to iterate through. Then integer arithmetic is used with `ProxyI`, incrementing by one to count the intervals. This integer arithmetic has no rounding errors, so `ProxyI` correctly counts the intervals. Then, inside the loop, the counter `ProxyI` is scaled and translated to the corresponding point in the interval from `Start` to `End`. This arithmetic will have some rounding errors, so `RealI` will often be not exactly the ideal number, but it will be close. The rounding errors will only affect the value of `RealI`; they will not affect the loop counter, `ProxyI`. So the loop counts correctly. (Getting the exact number is generally impossible, since it would not be representable in the floating-point format.)

This design solves the problem of rounding errors in the iterator causing it to be slightly above or below the end value, but it provides the additional benefit of avoiding compounded rounding errors over many additions. The rounding errors are limited to the few operations in `Start + I / NumberOfIntervals * (End - Start)`.

(Note: I almost never write in JavaScript, so I cannot assure the above code is proper JavaScript. Also note that the final value of `RealI` as calculated above might not be exactly `End`, because `End - Start + Start` in floating-point arithmetic does not necessarily produce `End`.)